# How do I tokenize using C strings?

Tags: c++, c-strings

How does one do this in **c strings**? If we have a **c string** of:

```c
char s[20] = "fd50 fd 50 fd 5  0";
```

And I want my 2D char array called `token` to contain the split string like this:

```c
token[0] = "fd"
token[1] = "50"
token[2] = "fd"
token[3] = "50"
token[4] = "fd"
token[5] = "50"
```

I need a method to split apart numbers and letters and store them seperately into a 2D char array.

I know how to tokenize with spaces but how does one tokenize like above?
Really don't understand how to do this with **c strings**.

So far what I have come up with in C++ is this:

```cpp
stringInputChecker(s);
 
std::vector <std::string> token;
std::stringstream check(s);
std::string buffer;
int checker = 1;

while(getline(check, buffer, ' ')) 
{ token.push_back(buffer); }
```

Here I used the `std::getline()` function that takes space as delimiter. That's what I have been using for my project.

But now I have to make it work when there are no spaces in between letters and numbers

But this uses `std::vector` which I don't want to use. I am confused on how to do this in **c**.

And the above code works only when there is a space. If no space then it won't work.

Comment: This is not a C question if you use C++ features.  In C the standard tool is `strtok()` which modifies the input string.  Alternatively use `strpbrk()` or `strchr()` to search for delimiters then make a copy  with `strdup()` or `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.

Comment: *"But this uses vectors and stuff which I don't want to use. I am confused on how to do this with normal means..."* `std::vector` **is the new normal.**

Comment: Thats why i tagged it with c and C++
I am allowed to mix in C with C++ in my project.

and yes standard approach is strtok() but that doesn't work when there is no space between fd and 50

Comment: If you want to use C++ features then it's not a C question and you shouldn't tag it as such.

Comment: I am using vectors because i don't know how to solve it without vectors... Thats why i asked how do i do this without vectors

Comment: @RainAnalyst You should edit your question title and mention there *(without using `std::vector`)*

Comment: Token is an array of char *.  You can use realloc to reisze the the array.  You need to write a function that finds the boundary, probably with a little state machine.

Comment: Simple. Go through the string character by character; when you see a space, save whatever you've seen so far into a new string (or char array). Then proceed and find the next string.  I don't see what's so difficult here..

Comment: So you want to just every 2 non-space characters in its own string?

Comment: "But this uses std::vector which I don't want to use" - Ehh, *why*? That's just stupid.

Comment: I wrote a you a pure C implementation below but if you are handed a C string and need to solve this in C++ then the first thing you should do is create a std::string then use modern C++ to solve this.

Comment: Use `operator>>` and set the number base to `hex`.  Loop through while there is data to be read.

Answer (score 2):

The question was initially tagged C and C++ and I wrote a pure C implementation.  If you want to use this in C++ then you want to apply the changes that @Chris mentioned below.  That said you should greatly prefer a pure C++ implementation (string, vector, auto_ptr etc) if you need a solution in C++.

The function `next()` identifies the boundary between tokens and `strndup_strip()` creates a copy of input string without space.  The rest is just populating and printing the `tokens` array:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *next(const char *s) {
    for(; isspace(*s); s++);
    if(isalpha(*s))
        for(; isalpha(*s); s++);
    else
        for(; isdigit(*s) || isspace(*s); s++);
    return s;
}

char *strndup_strip(const char *s, size_t n) {
    size_t m = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(!isspace(s[i])) m++;
    char *s2 = malloc(m+1);
    if(!s2) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t i = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if(!isspace(s[j]))
            s2[i++] = s[j];
    s2[i] = '\0';
    return s2;
}

char **tokenize(const char *s) {
    if(!s) return NULL;
    char **r = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for(; *s; i++) {
        const char *s2 = next(s);
        char *token = strndup_strip(s, s2 - s);
        if(!token || !*token) {
            free(token);
            break;
        }
        char **tmp = realloc(r, sizeof *r * (i+1));
        if(!tmp) {
            printf("realloc failed\n");
            free(r);
            return NULL;
        }
        r = tmp;
        r[i] = token;
        s = s2;
    }
    char **tmp = realloc(r, sizeof *r * (i+1));
    if(!tmp) {
        printf("realloc failed\n");
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }
    r = tmp;
    r[i] = NULL;
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "fd50 fd 50 fd 5  0";
    char **tokens = tokenize(s);
    if(!tokens) return 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; tokens[i]; i++) {
        printf("token[%zu] = \"%s\"\n", i, tokens[i]);
        free(tokens[i]);
    }
    free(tokens);
    return 0;
}
```

and example output:

```
token[0] = "fd"
token[1] = "50"
token[2] = "fd"
token[3] = "50"
token[4] = "fd"
token[5] = "50"
```

Comment: Given that the OP is apparently writing C code in C++ (a dubious practice, but we'll go with it) then A. they'll probably want to cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`; and B. you may want to use the wrapped headers, like `<cctype>` vs. `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: @Chris You are right, of course, but looks like op deleted the C tag and it'st a poor  C++ answer.  I added a bit context and if gets downvoted I will delete my answer.

Comment: It's a poor C++ answer, but it looks like the OP is probably learning C++ as "C with Classes" and this isn't a bad C answer at all. It gets an upvote from me.

Comment: For @RainAnalyst, note that much of Allan's code is concerned with managing resizing dynamically allocated arrays. This is exactly what `std::vector` handles for you.

Answer (score 1):

Rainy day here, so here's your solution...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void ) {
    char *str = "fd 50 rt 50 lt50 circle50"; // one sample string
    char **tok = NULL;
    char holding[ 32 ] = { 0 }; // a temp buffer to accumulate characters
    size_t n = 0, nt = 0;

    for( char *cp = str; *cp; cp++ ) {
        if( *cp == ' ' ) // ignore whitespace
            continue;

        if( !holding[0] ) { // first non-whitespace character
            holding[ n++ ] = *cp;
            continue;
        }

        if( isalpha( holding[0] ) && isalpha( *cp ) ) { // accumulate alpha chars
            holding[ n++ ] = *cp;
            continue;
        }

        if( isdigit( holding[0] ) && isdigit( *cp ) ) { // accumulate digits
            holding[ n++ ] = *cp;
            continue;
        }

        holding[ n ] = '\0'; // terminate buffer

        tok = realloc( tok, (nt+1) * sizeof *tok ); // extend array of ptrs
        /* verification of success omitted for brevity */
        tok[ nt++ ] = strdup( holding ); // copy the string
        /* and, same again */

        n = 0; // reset
        holding[ n++ ] = *cp; // store whatever is here
    }

    if( n ) { // handle what remains in buffer
        holding[ n ] = '\0';
        tok = realloc( tok, (nt+1) * sizeof *tok );
        /* here, too! */
        tok[ nt++ ] = strdup( holding );
        /* and also here */
    }

    // proof
    for( size_t i = 0; i < nt; i++ )
        printf( "tok[%u] = \"%s\"\n", i, tok[i] );

    // free()'ing the ptrs left as an exercise for the OP

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
tok[0] = "fd"
tok[1] = "50"
tok[2] = "rt"
tok[3] = "50"
tok[4] = "lt"
tok[5] = "50"
tok[6] = "circle"
tok[7] = "50"
```

This could be *simplified* a bit, but why bother? Stretched out like this is, it is easy to see what's happening and where it happens.

It should be noted that the `<ctype.h>` functions expect `unsigned char` parameters, so there's a risk of *sign extension* if this code is used "*as is*" with anything other than 7-bit ASCII... Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Check that `holding` doesn't overflow?  I probably wouldn't initialize `holding` as it's used in a loop so it's false sense of security that it does anything for you (if you can move it in the loop then it's fair game).

Comment: @AllanWind Good point... So many hazards in life, eh? `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string contains hexadecimal tokens:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string text_data = "fd50 fd 50 fd 5  0";
    std::vector<int>  numbers;
    int               value_read;
    std::stringstream text_stream(text_data);
    while (text_stream >> std::hex >> value_read)
    {
        numbers.push_back(value_read);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions seem either overly complicated or possibly incorrect.

To parse a string that only contains pairs of hex chars, is even in length, and doesn't contain any whitespace (e.g. "fd50fd50fd50"), then it's really hard to beat this:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& s) {
    size_t pairs = s.size() / 2;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pairs; i++) {
        tokens.push_back(s.substr(i * 2, 2));
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

If you need an implementation that supports an input string that may or may not have spaces between characters, then a more generic implementation:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& s) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string tmp;
    char prev = {};
    while (pos < s.size()) {
        if (std::isalnum(s[pos])) {
            tmp.push_back(s[pos]);
            if (tmp.size() == 2) {
                tokens.push_back(tmp);
                tmp.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    // optional handling of an odd character and the end that isn't part of a pair
    // if (tmp.size() > 0) {
    //    tokens.push_back(tmp);
    // }

    return tokens;
}
```

In either of the above cases, you can call the above helper function with either a std::string or a C char[] array (assuming it's null terminated). Or even with a string literal.

Your original string (since it has spaces, it's only valid for the second implementation):

```
char s[] = "fd50 fd 50 fd 5  0";
std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize(std::string(s, 20));
```

Or like this (works with either implementation):

```
char s[] = "fd50fd50fd50";
std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize(s);
```

Or As a literal.

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize("fd50fd50fd50");
```

Or with a pointer obtained somewhere else:

```
const char* s = getInputString();
tokens = tokenize(s);
```

Comment: I think you should more explicit state your assumption that it's a pair of hex chars with random spaces as op did not say that in the question.  "overly complicated or possibly incorrect" is not appropriate.  If you want help others improve their answers comment on them instead and let your answer stand on it's on merit.   As op removed the C tag, your answer being in C++ is by default the better one, and with your assumptions it's elegant.